# Change Density Using AVD Manager

Tags: android, screen

I have created 3 Device Descriptions that mimic the latest models of Samsung mobile devices (S2, S3 & S4). Although I enter the diagonal screen length and pixels (w x h), I am unable to see a change in density across the 3 AVDs when I start them using the AVD Manager (screen caps below). Did I miss something or does the tool support density changes? Also, this is poorly documented.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a quit and re-enter, things worked fine but the density value never updated, always reads 320 - probably based on my laptops screen. Also DON'T use option 'Scale display to real size". Let the emulator do the rendering and move app to device for native testing.